# Basic JPEG manipulation with Carrierwave Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, carrierwave, osx-server, mogrify

What's the least painful way to get basic JPEG scaling available to CarrierWave on a Mac (Leopard) Server? I'm trying to avoid installing the full ImageMagick suite and all its myriad dependencies as this server is stable right now and, well, ImageMagick scares me as it litters /usr/local/bin with PDF, Font, fax, bmp, png, etc utilities which we won't need.

All we need out of CarrierWave is for it to create jpeg thumbs from uploaded JPEGs. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

try https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew. You could install the required libraries using brew into user/home directories. Which makes it easy to revert back with out messing with your mac defaults.

Comment: I wanted to use **homebrew** but it wants me to delete `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/local/bin` which isn't an option on this server as git, passenger, mysql, mongodb and some other utilities are currently sourced there and in active use. They also require you to *recursively* change owner of `/usr/local/` from **root** to your local admin's name...which concerns me when all these other utilities are running fine with root as owner.